# URL rewrite not showing effect

Tags: url-rewriting

I have written below rule in my urlrewrite.xml file of my struts application which is using tuckey filter 4.0. We have a requirement in our application that a url of type say http:localhost:8080/tgld/viewTopic?guidelinename=A&topicFile=B needs to be replaced by URL of type http:localhost:8080/tgld/etg/topicFile . some kind of masking for the original URL as it looks shaby with so many parameters. URLrewrite jar 4.9 is already in WEB-INF and my http://localhost:8080/rewrite-status page is loading fine.

here tgld is the application context and viewTopic is my action name

it will be great if someone will help us here

```
   <rule>
        <from>/viewTopic/*</from>
        <to>/etg/$2</to>
     </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Change the rule as below

```
<rule>
    <from>^/viewTopic?guidelinename=(.*)&topicFile=(.*)$</from>
    <to type="redirect">/tgld/etg/$2</to>
</rule>
```